# How do i put the icons in one row with the radiobuttons in a form?

Tags: html, css

does someone know how to put the icons in one row and put a little space between these choice options.

I need it in the middle of the form so vertically and horizontally.
I've google'd a lot around but found nothing that solves it.

I tried it with margin left and top.

[image]

```
<form style="height: 80px; width: 900px; margin: 50px auto; border: 3px solid; border-radius: 10px;"
      wicket:id="brandChooseForm">
    <div>
        <span wicket:id="brandRadioChoice">
    <input wicket:id="gmxnetRadio" type="radio" value="GMXNET" style="margin-top: auto">
    <img alt="Gmxnetlogo" title="GMX.net"><label>net</label>

    <input wicket:id="netidRadio" type="radio" value="NETID">
    <img  style="height: 50px; width: auto;" alt="netId"
         title="netId">

    <input wicket:id="webdeRadio" type="radio" value="WEBDE">
    <img alt="Webdelogo" title="Web.de">

    <input wicket:id="mailcomRadio" type="radio" value="MAILCOM">
    <img alt="Mailcomlogo" title="Mail.com">

    <input wicket:id="gmxcomRadio" type="radio" value="GMXCOM">
    <img alt="Gmxcomlogo" title="GMX.com"><label>com</label>
    </span>
    </div>
    <p></p>
</form>
```

```
input[type="radio"]{
     text-align: center;
}
img {
    width: 90px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

Comment: You should be using `<label>` so the user can click the image to set the radio button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't apply any height on images, use display: flex and align-items: center, and it will center horizontally all your elements in one line

```css
form > div > span, form > div {display: flex; align-items: center;}
form > div {height: 100%; justify-content: center;}
```

```html
<form style="height: 80px; width: 900px; margin: 50px auto; border: 3px solid; border-radius: 10px;"
      wicket:id="brandChooseForm">
    <div>
        <span wicket:id="brandRadioChoice">
    <input wicket:id="gmxnetRadio" type="radio" value="GMXNET" >
    <img alt="Gmxnetlogo" title="GMX.net"><label>net</label>

    <input wicket:id="netidRadio" type="radio" value="NETID">
    <img  style="width: auto;" alt="netId"
         title="netId">

    <input wicket:id="webdeRadio" type="radio" value="WEBDE">
    <img alt="Webdelogo" title="Web.de">

    <input wicket:id="mailcomRadio" type="radio" value="MAILCOM">
    <img alt="Mailcomlogo" title="Mail.com">

    <input wicket:id="gmxcomRadio" type="radio" value="GMXCOM">
    <img alt="Gmxcomlogo" title="GMX.com"><label>com</label>
    </span>
    </div>
    <p></p>
</form>
```

Comment: I works but i need it in the middle of the black  border. Do you know how to do this? Thank you anyway

Comment: check the answer now